# Sum cells in an Excel date table that match given criteria

Tags: excel, cumulative-sum

| Year | March | June | Sept | December |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2002 | 17.2 | 23.8 | 21.3 | 74.9 |
| 2003 | 23.5 | 11.5 | 53.8 | 29.2 |
| 2004 | 87.1 | 82.1 | 48.2 | 65.7 |

The Year column is the first day of the year. The quarterly columns are the first day of the month provided, ie. March 1st. I would like a formula which, with a provided date, would provide the sums of the four quarter figures surrounding that date. For example, if the date is November 17, 2003, I would like to sum the data of the months starting in the prior 100 days of that month's start (53.8), including that month's start, if relevent, as well as all the months starting in the following 250 days of that month's end (29.2 + 87.1 + 82.1). The sum would be (53.8+29.2+87.1+82.1) = 252.2. (I think my question is structured so that I will always get the sum of 4, and only 4, quarters.

I can't figure out how to do it.

Comment: What if the date provided (November 17, 2003 in your question) fits exactly one of the quarters, like September 01, 2003? Would still the result be 252.2? or would it be 181.6?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if I understood properly your logic, but you may benefit from SUMPRODUCT and double unary operators to do array calculations and get your desired output:

[image]

First case is if your month headers are single numbers (I dit it first like this because it's easier to understand the logic). So March is always month 3rd, June is 6th and so on. Formula in this case is:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(DATE(A2:A4;B1:E1;1)>=(A7-100))*--(DATE(A2:A4;B1:E1;1)<=(A7+250))*B2:E4)
```

Second case is if your month headers are really numeric dates but formatted to be seen only as months, so the real value of each cell would be 01/03/2023, 01/06/2023 and so on.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(DATE(A12:A14;MONTH(B11:E11);1)>=(A17-100))*--(DATE(A12:A14;MONTH(B11:E11);1)<=(A17+250))*B12:E14)
```

Third case is i your month headers are strings and text, so the values are March, June, and so on.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(DATE(A22:A24;{3;6;9;12};1)>=(A27-100))*--(DATE(A22:A24;{3;6;9;12};1)<=(A27+250))*B22:E24)
```

Please notice my argument separator is `;` so adapt it as you need.

Comment: For " , " as the argument separator: =SUMPRODUCT(--(DATE(A22:A24,{3,6,9,12},1)>=(A27-100))*--(DATE(A22:A24,{3,6,9,12},1)<=(A27+250))*B22:E24)

Answer (score 0):

One option could be:

```
=LET(tc,CHOOSE({1,2},TOCOL(DATE(A2:A4,MONTH(B1:E1),1)),TOCOL(B2:E4)),dc,INDEX(tc,0,1),SUM(INDEX(FILTER(tc,(dc>EDATE(H2,-3))*(dc<=EDATE(H2,9))),0,2)))
```

I assume that you have correct dates in header row formatted as month names. Instead of subtracting and adding days, I operate with months (-3 and +9).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This formula may be simpler:

```
=LET(dc;DATE(YEAR(A2:A4);MONTH(B1:E1);1);SUM((dc>EDATE(H2;-3))*(dc<=EDATE(H2;9))*B2:E4))
```

It assumes `A2:A4` are dates (as per statement) not numbers, and the target date is in `H2`.